# Server to server transfer using AJAX

Tags: ajax, data-transfer

This questions was asked during one of the interview. How to transfer data from one server to another using AJAX? Is it really possible?

Comment: job interview?  guessing you didn't get it

Comment: stupid question. don't join the company even if they offer you a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is generally used on the client side, not usually the server side.
It sends requests to a server.

You probably need to provide more information about what you are trying to achieve to get a decent answer.

If you are wanting to transfer data from a "client" to a server then you could send the data in a variety of ways - especially with AJAX.  Just how depends on what data type and size.  Requests from a client to server (HTTP) can include POST data, which can carry your data to the server.

If you are using AJAX on a client and wanting to use it to transfer data from one remote server to another then you could get AJAX on your client to call a script on the server that would instigate the transfer from the server to another server in some way. (such as FTP or SCP maybe - or even using a server to server HTTP POST)

If you can be a little more specific about what you need to do then I will try and give you a better answer.